# (Approximate) Explicit solutions for mass matrix DAEs with nil-potent linear dynamics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, differential-algebraic-equations

I am writing a [package](https://github.com/freemin7/NilPotentIntegrator.jl) to solve linear differential equations of the form $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = A\vec{x}$ where $A$ is nil potent. The knowledge of the nil potency guarantees that the matrix exponential just produces polynomials, which can be explicitly calculated and evaluated much faster than a matrix exponential.

I am looking into ways to expand my package and one way to do so would be to exploit knowledge about mass matrix DAEs of the form:
$$M \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = A\vec{x}$$
where $M$ is singular and $A$ is nilpotent. However since i am unfamiliar with DAEs i am unsure whether there exist any explicit knowledge about the solution structure i could exploit.

My questions are:

- Is there explicit solution for initial value problems of Linear (mass matrix) DAEs?
- If there is no global explicit solution, how could i use knowledge of the global solution of $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = A\vec{x}$ to solve $M \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = A\vec{x}$ approximately?
- How would i calculate the local approximation error to do step size control in your proposed scheme?

Comment: I might be unreasonable here since the explicit solution probably involves an index reduction using Differentiation and Gaussian Elimination or Pantelides algorithm to transform it into an ODE. Suggestions are still welcome

Comment: Regarding the last point: if you look at MatLab DAEs documentation you should find the references they used to implement those algorithms

Comment: The Mathematica documentation is the better source for this IMHO: [NDSolveDAE](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html)

Comment: I meant a research paper that explains the theory behind the solver. From a quick view it seems to me that there are only lots of examples on how to solve it with Mathematica.